# Computing evidence for least-squares fit

Tags: regression, bayesian

I'm at a loss trying to implement Bayesian model selection for standard least-squares polynomials fits.

I have three polynomials of order $1$, $2$, and $3$, and a sequence of $(x,y)$ data points. After performing least-squares fitting of the three polynomials, I want to select the one with the maximum evidence (marginal likelihood).

Given a model $H_{i\in\{1,2,3\}}$ with parameters $w_i$, a set of inputs $x$ and outputs $y$, I need to compute the evidence
$$
p(y\mid x ,H_i) = \int p(y\mid x,w,H_i)p(w\mid H_i) \, \mathrm{d}w
$$
For the cubic polynomial $H_3$, w is a 4-element vector $w=[a,b,c,d]$, and 
$$
H_3 = a + bx + cx^2 + dx^3
$$

So far, so good.

I want my prior $p(w\mid H_i)$ to be as flat as possible, so my plan is to use an improper prior $p(w\mid H_i)=1$. Or do I have to use something more proper, like a Gaussian with a crazy covariance? Because otherwise, the integral would reduce to just the integral of the Gaussian PDF $p(y\mid x,w,H_i)=1$ for all my three $H_i$, wouldn't it?

How do people normally do this thing?

Or perhaps I'm just confused about the form of the integral. $\int p(y\mid x,w,H) \, dy=1$, of course, since it is a probability distribution, but the integral I want is $\int p(y\mid x,w,H)\,dw$.

So my question is: how do I compute that integral?

Comment: I believe that with Bayesian methods you usually want to use the conjugate prior distribution.

Comment: I've been looking at [this page](http://alumni.media.mit.edu/~tpminka/statlearn/demo/), and what I want (at least what I think I want) is the integral at the top of that page, but with a flat prior.

Does that make sense?

Comment: You're leaving a lot unclear.  You say "Given a model $H_{i\in\{1,2,3\}}$, and leave me to surmise, in part based on what you say _after_ that, that you mean that $H_i$ is the hypothesis that you should be fitting the $i$th-degree polynomial.  You say "marginal likelihood", but if this is supposed to be Bayesian, I would think you mean "posterior probability" ("likelihood" is what you multiply the prior by, and then normalize, to get the posterior).  Why would you be doing least-squares fitting rather than finding probability distributions of the coefficients?  And what are you....

Comment: ...assuming about probability distributions of the errors?

Comment: As far as I understand, what I'm after is the normalising constant used to compute the posterior over the parameters w. The posterior is $$p(w|x,y,H)=\frac{p(y|x,w,H)p(w|H)}{p(y|x,H)}$$ (using Bayes' rule) and what I am after is the denominator.

Comment: Regarding the PDFs of the errors, I am assuming normal-distributed errors with equal variance, because otherwise my least-squares fit isn't necessarily the maximum-likelihood fit, right?

Comment: In the Bayes equation above, $p(y|x,w,H)$ is easy enough to compute, using a normal distribution with the mean and covariance I get from my least-squares fit of the parameters $w$. And for $p(w|H)$, I would like to use something as flat as possible; so I hope I can just substitute it with 1 and forget about it, in order not to put any constraints on the parameters. The remaining question is how to compute the integral in the denominator.

Comment: @MichaelHardy, to answer your question about why I'm using LS fitting instead of finding PDFs of the coefficients: What I want to do is to determine the simplest polynomial that can explain a given set of data, and I thought least-squares (maximum likelihood) fitting plus (Bayesian) model selection would be a good way to do it.

Comment: If you're using improper uniform priors on the coefficients, then I think ordinary least squares might coincide with posterior expected values (but that depends on which assumptions you're making about the distribution of the errors).  But generally I think you should be report posterior probability distributions of those coefficients if you're using Bayesian methods.

Comment: OK. Thanks a lot for your input. I think I'm starting to lean towards using something simpler, like AIC, to do my model selection. That solves the problem at hand (I'm not required to use Bayesian methods, it just feels better to do so...), although I still would like to know how to compute the marginal likelihood. But for now, maybe we can consider this case closed.